# Faces with more than four vertices for 3D printing

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

When I'm making planar faces with more than 4 vertices I can do this with <kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>.

<kbd>F</kbd> will create a single face.

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> will create multiple faces made up of triangles.

Which of these is the best? I'm planning on using the model for 3d printing. Will a face made of more than 4 vertices cause problems?

Comment: I'd create the model using only quads (faces of four vertices). At the end you can still triangulate the complete mesh with Alt T, but keeping the topology with quads untill that step has many benefits. There are also specific tools to setup a printable mesh.

Comment: *" Will a face made of more than 4 vertices cause problems"* it will very likely. Tris for printing will be used anyway so they shouldn't be a problem as long as topology they form is suitable for the end product. Though quads may be preferred from modelling convinience point of view.

Comment: I tried Ctrl T, and it did a great job converting to triangles, I guess I'll model with what is easiest and convert at the end using Ctrl T

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use ngons for printing. Not even quads. Send triangulated mesh to the printer.

Ngons (and quads) are very convenient to work with. You can use knife tool on them easily. Because of this I would recommend using <kbd>F</kbd> when making the model.

For export for printing, use the [Triangulate modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/triangulate.html) and the [*Wire* and *Use All Edges* option for Object Display](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/display.html). This allows you to control how the model will exactly triangulate and how it will print. You have more control over the triangulation and you can set the same *Beauty* algorithm for triangulating ngons as the <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> command does by default.

Most exporters will allow you to apply modifiers on export, so you don't have to triangulate you model in Blender which makes it easier to do changes on the model later.