# Is there a way to have more control when face-flattening so you can decide which neighboring faces get distorted?

Tags: edit-mode, 3d-printing, hard-ops

I am having a tough time trying to get the faces in my mesh nice and flat before 3d-printing so the finished print doesn't show a bunch of triangles I didn't intend to be there.

To be clear, I know that STL only supports tris. What I am trying to figure out how to do is to get my mesh to a state where the only tris which are visible on the final print are the ones that I put there... NOT the ones which result from triangulating a distorted face.

It seems like there should be a way to flatten a face (like you do with loop tools), but have some control over which of the neighboring faces get distorted in the process. That way I could do something like work front-to-back, flattening faces as I go, without distorting the stuff I've already fixed. There might be a point where I realize I have to make a change to the design of the thing in order to get things flattened, but I'd rather do that than have the design get changed by the stl exporter in a way I didn't intend.

For example, the below object has faces which are supposed to be flat. I tried to keep them that way, but as I made adjustments to the model they got distorted a bit.
[image]
If I flatten #1, then it distorts 2. If I then flatten 2, it distorts 1, 3, and 5.

If I select all and try Cleanup->Make Planar Faces, it helps a little but doesn't fix it completely... So what I'd like to try to do for example is something like:

1. S Z 0 for #1
2. Loop tools-> flatten for #2, but somehow restrict it so that the vertices of #1 don't move
3. Repeat with one face at a time until they're all or I have to make some change to the model to make everything fit together better.

Things I have tried:

- Endlessly iterate with loop tool's face flattener
- Cleanup->Make Planar Faces
- Separate faces which I've already cleaned up off in to their own objects so they can't be edited accidentally, but then when I re-combine them the vertices don't line up anymore and round-and-around we go.
- Hide faces I've already cleaned up, but that makes it pretty hard to work
- 3D print the thing and just try to sand down the edges I didn't want to be there (not going well so far).
- [This solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112018/faces-with-more-than-four-vertices-for-3d-printing), which is probably the closest to a solution but I still find that if I make two tris flat wrt each other then their neighbors get screwed up, so I'm back where I started.

There has to be a better way (I am open to using paid addons - I have HopsCutter and a few others) and I would very much appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: I find it to be a better way to model whatever you need with the sides you need to be flat already flat from the beginning.  Else than that what you do depends on the situation and since you haven't showed any pictures of the geometry it's impossible to advice. Could you maybe edit the question and share some pictures?

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys I do generally try to do as you describe (flat faces being flat from the beginning), but sometimes things get distorted as a result of various things like adding bevels or booleans. Anyway I added a picture of an object and tried to better describe what's happening.

Comment: Adding bevels(ctrl+b) does not make non-planar faces. You can also set Iterations to high number for Mesh->Cleanup->Make Planar Faces for the algorithm to be repeated many times.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Adding bevels can make non planar faces if you're beveling intersecting edges in a way that creates a triangle where three edges intersect. Any time you do something that creates an ngon there seems to be a chance it distorts the face.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Also I said in the post that make planar faces doesn't seem to do the trick. What I'm wondering is if there a way to constrain which faces get distorted when you're flattening their neighbors (see title of post)?